# How can I send focused window beneath other windows like Alt+Esc do in Windows?

Tags: macos, shortcut, window-manager

I don't want to minimize it (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) or hide it (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). I want other windows to be on top of my focused window when I press some shortcut or fire some macro/script/whatever. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Same app or different app? Same app is cmd/` different app is cmd/tab

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't want to switch to another app/window, I want to send focused window back/beneath.

Comment: so, same app? cmd `

Comment: arghhh, no! I don't care what app is beneath focused window

Comment: so... you don't want to switch windows in the same app... yet you don't want to switch to another app. That kind of leaves us out of alternatives :/